# If $A$ is an open box in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $E$ is the half-plane, show that $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> (Tao Vol.2, P.182) If $A$ is an open box in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $E$ is the half-plane $E: = \{ (x_1, ... , x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n > 0 \}$, show that $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$.

In the previous exercise, we are asked to prove that if $A$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, then $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap (0, \infty)) + m^*(A \setminus (0, \infty))$. This can be proven using the definition of the outer measure; that is, for $A = (a,b)$, $m^*(A) = b-a$ and we can similarly compute $m^*(A \cap (0, \infty)) + m^*(A \setminus (0, \infty))$.

The author suggests to use this hint. I am thinking about the induction on the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For $n=1$, by the previous exercise, it is true. We make an assumption for the dimension $< n$. Consider the dimension $n$. Let $A' \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $E' = \{(x_1, ... , x_{n-1}) : x_k > 0\}$. Then, by the induction hypothesis, $m^*(A') = m^*(A' \setminus E')+ m^*(A' \cap E')$. Let $A = A' \times (a,b)$ and $E = E' \times (0, \infty)$.

I am stuck here. By subadditivity, I only need to show that $m^*(A) \ge m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$. I also know that $m^*(A' \times (a,b)) \le m^*(A')m^*((a,b))$, but this inequality does not seem really useful in this proof.

Is this problem solvable using my method? If not, could you suggest some way of approaching this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is late but yes there is a much easier approach. $E$ is the half plane and $A$ is an open box. So both $A \cap E$ and $A \setminus E$ are boxes too. And directly calculating $\text{vol}$ for boxes is easy. Then use the fact that $m^\ast = \text{vol}$ for boxes.